# Creating RAW Sockets tutorial/explanation?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

So Im trying to further my understanding of sockets, but I want to start out at the lowest level first (well in C, not assembly lol)

However most sites that I deal with use the SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM. However I have read around on Beejs guide....but I don't know if that actually deals with RAW sockets or not.

I'll obviously need to call SOCK_RAW in my call to sockets, but theirs not really a WHOLE lot of information about it. And this is just for learning purposes, i always try to understand the root of whats going on in abstraction.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+raw+socket+sample+source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Linux, I would look at the man pages for [socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) and [packet](http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet) as a start. From here and after reading a few other man pages to figure out how to actually [send](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) packets on the wire, I'd install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and experiment with sending hand-crafted packets and using Wireshark to capture and analyze them. You can learn a lot about the different network layers this way and how you can tweak different values in various headers.